# Stop and prepare collectionview while it is loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionView` (productCollectionView) which gets data from the service based on the category (electronic, cars, goods, etc..).

Let's imagine that user decided to pull data in electronic category, while data is loading, user has changed the category and fetch the new dataset.

I have implemented the following logic, but it is slow a little bit. Is there a better approach?

```
-(void) refreshProducts
{
    if([self.pElements count]){
        [self.pElements removeAllObjects];
        [self.productCollectionView reloadData];
    }
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
        [self loadFromURL]; // fetch new data
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });
    });
}

-(void)loadFromURL {   

    NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSString * category = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"category"];
    if (category != NULL && ![category isEqualToString: @""]) {
        params[@"category"] = category;
    }

   // offset increments based on scrolling down, +20
    params[@"offset"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",offset];

    [self.manager POST:PRODUCT_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id responseObject) {
            // getting only 20 data every time, and append to the existing array
            [self.pElements addObjectsFromArray:responseObject];
            [self.productCollectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    }];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   __weak ProductCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];        
    cell.productImage.image = [cell.productImage.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    NSString *URL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/images/%@", [[[[pElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"pdetail"] objectForKey:@"images"]objectForKey:@"pimagePath"]];
    cell.productImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10;        
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [cell.productImage setImageWithURLRequest:request
                          placeholderImage:nil
                                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                       cell.productImage.image = image;
                                       [cell setNeedsLayout];

                                   } failure:nil];

    return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is too vague for us to help much.

It looks like your `loadFromURL` method loads ALL of your products, then tells the collection view to reload once it's done.

If true, that will create a lag because nothing will happen until everything is done loading. Better to request one item at at a time in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`, save it's contents to a file on disk, and then install that content into the cell at that index path, assuming it is still on-screen. If a cell gets scrolled off-screen before it can be loaded then you can still load its data from a file on disk, and not re-download it.

That approach will only load the cells that are visible, and each of those will be displayed as its content finished loading, making the screen start updating much sooner.

Comment: actually `loadFromURL` has a parameter which is `offset`, every time calling this method, it only brings 20 items at a time, not ALL of items. I do not get all images, in the `loadURL`, I keep imageURLs, and then use it `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: I have also updated my question.. just added more code to make it clearer.

Comment: But you're calling reloadData after fetching the records, which forces the entire collection view to reload.

Comment: Sorry, my initial question I purposely put it there to convey my question. But when I updated the question and put entire code, it is not in the actual code because it is already in the `loadFromURL`

Answer (score 0):

Excluding speeding up the server or narrowing the query, the only other means to get computational savings is by cancelling the currently in-flight request when the user changes categories.

To do this, keep the task in a property...

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSURLSessionDataTask *productTask;
```

Then cancel the last post (if it exists) before starting a new one...

```
[self.productTask cancel];
self.productTask = [self.manager POST:PRODUCT_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id responseObject) {
    // etc.
```

Beyond that, there are some UI tricks that make the user's perception of time pass more quickly.  (@DuncanC has a good idea to load just visible rows and reload as you get them, but it's not clear you can get them in smaller batches).  A few other ideas of that ilk are progress bars, activity indicators, or [kitten videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E__F5a2pQco).